# Setup multiple domains on one sever

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I recently bought a new domain name. I currently have 3 domains and 2 servers (both running Ubuntu 16.04) from <[digitOcean](http://digitalocean.com)>. 2 of the domains are pointing to the same server. I tried setting up the server so that both domains function on the same server but with different root directories. I modified the `000-default.conf.` file located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` then tried restarting Apache2 but it refused. Here's the response I got:

```
root@<username>:~# sudo service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                 [fail] 
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
env: apache2ctl: No such file or directory
```

I also tried running `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` but all I get is an error message saying `sudo: a2dissite: command not found`.

[This](http://www.joabj.com/Programs/Apache/Apache-Subdomains.html) is the tutorial I was following. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the system is telling you that it didn't find something: `env: apache2ctl: No such file or directory` then you can use this web page to search for it: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=apache2ctl&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any

That page tells you that it's the `apache2` package that contains that file. Do you have `apache2` installed? E.g. :

```
dpkg -s apache2
```

If it's not installed, then do:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Then redo your command.

Comment: I ran the `dpkg -s apache2` command and this is the output I got. I'm not sure is this means that it's installed not.
    `Package: apache2
    Status: install ok installed
    Priority: optional
    Section: httpd
    Installed-Size: 464`

Comment: When you don't understand a command, you can use `man` (as in "manual") on Unix systems. So if you do not understand the output of `dpkg` then you can type `man dpkg` and try to understand what is shown. Back to your OP. Try `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH' ; sudo apache2ctl configtest`. What does that produce?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
`

Comment: I checked, it would appear the problem was not Apache2 as it was not installed. The server uses Nginx.